# Does the universal set operate as the Von Neumann universe in non well founded set theories?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, ordinals, universal-property

I've been researching non well founded set theories (E.g. NF, NFU, etc.) and have been wondering if there are any similarities between the universal set & Von Neumann universe ? Or if there the Von Neumann universe exists in some fashion in non well founded set theories. The reason I ask this question is because, from my understanding the Von Neumann universe doesn't deal with sets that 'self refer'. if someone could confirm or correct this for me that would be great.

Comment: In the presence of foundation, the stages of the von Neumann universe plays a similar role to a tower of Grothendieck universes, stratifying the sets into a hierarchy of levels. In contrast to Grothendieck universes which are very "fat" (e.g. no amount of iteration of powerset can escape to the next level of the tower), the stages of $V$ are "thin" (only a single powerset suffices.) But regardless of how "fat" the stages are, this avoids Russell's paradox since the Russell set wouldn't be in any of these stages as its members have unbounded stage.

Comment: @C7X if the universal set is an unbounded stage (forever continuing, even further than inaccessible cardinals) does that mean the universal set is just a single 'layer' and not divided? Also are there any examples of a universal set operating as von Neumann universe in some model of set theory? If so what are the implications of it?

Comment: By "its members have unbounded stage" I mean that for any stage we can find a member of the universal set that's above that stage, the universal set can still be sliced up (e.g. $V\cap x$ where $x$ is some stage) but no matter how high of a stage we restrict ourselves to we will always be missing some part of $V$.

Comment: The universal set will act like $V$ if we can prove that we can slice the universal set up into levels such that each set is in a level. ZFC, although not having a universal set, can sort of do this idea since it proves $\forall x\exists\alpha(x\in V_\alpha)$.

Comment: @C7X So in non well founded set theories (NF, NFU) does the universal set acts as the Von Neumann universe (being cut into layers) or as something else.

Comment: I don't know much about how non-well-fouded set theories work, but due to the nature of stratified formulae I'd expect that well-fonundedness of the levels is a nearby concept. So I'd think yes, V is still slicable into layers

Comment: @C7X your answer does appear correct. I guess in a non well founded set theory you would have to use some theorem to satisfy that the union of all sets is a set.